# Change directories in Jupyter

Tags: python, directory, jupyter-notebook

I want to load a csv file on Jupyter but i have trouble getting to my desktop and hence reading the file. This is what i'm using to change directories without success.

```
import os 
import sys
import pandas as pd 

module_name = 'os'

if module_name in sys.modules:
  print("Installed")
else:
  print("Not Installed")

print(os.getcwd())

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop')
```

and this is the error that i'm getting:

```
yes
/home/jovyan/binder
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-501d5c14cdac> in <module>
     12 print(os.getcwd())
     13 
---> 14 os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop'
```

I'm new to Jupyter and Python, and i'm not sure why this is happening. Did anyone had the same issue?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, since i am quite stuck

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `os.getcwd()` printed a path that starts with `/home` indicates to me you're using linux (or WSL if you're on Windows). Make sure `C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop` is an actual path that you're jupyter session can access (to see what folders exist in root, use `!ls /` in a jupyter notebook cell).

I suspect your jupyter session is being hosted using WSL, which means your normal Windows C drive file system can be found at `/mnt/c/`. Try:

```
os.chdir('/mnt/c/Users/Mike/Desktop')
```

Comment: Hi @Jay, yes i'm using Windows. Unfortunately what you said above does not work, and i get the same error. Also when i type !ls/ i get the following error:/bin/sh: 1: ls/: not found

Comment: @XristosSolwmou There's a space between `!ls` and `/`. Copy this exactly `!ls /`. This command will list all the directories in the root folder. You can navigate from there to find where you might find your desktop folder.

Comment: So i get the following                                                                        
bin   dev  home  lib64 mnt  proc  run  srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib  media opt  root  sbin  sys  usr

Comment: How would the path look like for finding my Desktop